# Why physical memory keep increase and virtual memory size will increase a little after a long time on linux

Tags: c++, linux, memory-leaks, virtual-memory

The program is written in `C++` on `X86_64 Linux 2.6.32.12`, there are two casees, one case will generate one file for each file injected, and send out through `UDP(Version A)`; and another case will not generate file, send the injected file directly through `UDP(Version B)`.

===============VersionA Statistic Graphic===========================
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bxI5.png
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bxI5.png]

================VersionB Statictic Graphic===========================
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEnKc.png
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEnKc.png]

I have use `valgrind` verified these two cases, the report is same, not see any memory leak.
Is this caused by the linux kernel memory mapping? the test machine has `64G` memory.
Is this `memory leak`?

Update Information:

In the `Version A`, we use `UNIX socket` to send the original file content to another application, then receive the process result generate the required file. As the graphic shows, the physical memory will increase. I have tried another case, don't send the file through the Unix socket, use `system` function, call the another application generate the required file, it shows that the memory will not increase. It seems new generated file is not the problem, it caused by the Unix socket. We use socket pool, and i use `lsof`, there is no extra socket opened. Is `Unix socket` will occupied the memory?

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that version A is allocating memory for the file contents, and the memory manager isn't returning the memory to the system when it is freed (as it correctly knows the memory will be reused).

I wouldn't worry, the kernel will re-use the memory if there is pressure for memory.

Comment: In the Version A, we use UNIX socket to send the original file content to another application, then receive the process result generate the required file. As the graphic shows, the physical memory will increase. I have tried another case, don't send the file through the Unix socket, use system function, call the another application generate the required file, it shows that the memory will not increase. It seems new generated file is not the problem, it caused by the Unix socket. We use socket pool, and i use lsof, there is no extra socket opened. Is Unix socket will occupied the memory?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you are getting memory fragmentation which is stopping blocks of memory being returned to the OS.

Comment: First i also think it is the memory fragmentation reason, i also use tcmalloc, and jemalloc, the result is same, i didn't known tcmalloc or jemalloc well, seems them will divided memory into small block, large block.